# matching regular expression with semicolon in sentences

Tags: javascript, regex

here is a program to  match a regular expression

```
string="Mozilla/5.0 (Series40; NOKIA311/03.81; Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1) Gecko/20100401 S40OviBrowser/2.2.0.0.31";
regex=/(nokia).*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/i
regex.exec(string)
```

My problem is its not matching to NOKIA and 311

Could anyone help.please

Comment: Can you make it more elaborate....??

Comment: i want to extract model number from given string above...but the regex given does not extract it..if semicolon is removed it works fine..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `.*`, which tries to match as much as possible.  It actually ends up matching the entire rest of the string and only leaves the `1` from the very end to satisfy the `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`.  You need a more specific regex, perhaps:

```
/nokia(\d+)/i
/nokia(.*?)\//i
```

The `.*?` makes the `.*` reluctant, so it will only match up to the first slash.

Answer (score 0):

use the regex `/NOKIA([\d\w]*)/i`

Which will match the pattern NOKIA and any number or word without spaces

Comment: `[\d\w]` is the same as `\w`.